# Best approach to save token in vue with laravel sanctum

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vuex

I am working on app that is developed in laravel and vuejs. Now I am trying to make login/logout part using laravel sanctum.

Now I have following scenario:

I already have the methods for login/logout/register in backend, but how to deal with vue part?

So based on token, I can make any request in backend, but how can I save the token in frontend?

On the whole internet I saw localstorage (but it's safe or not?) or vuex (which also it's saved in localstorage)

Which is the best approach to deal with storing token?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

#### It is very hard to answer, without knowing your exact server-side solution, or your client-side needs.

Here are some links to research further:

- Vuex will not store in [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) by default, and will not persist a page reload.
- localstorage will persist, and can therefore be a security concern.
- [Sessionstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) will persist a page reload, but not after a browser restart.
- A combination of refresh token in localstorage and access token in sessionstorage might be a good solution.
- [HttpOnly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)  is also a viable solution, since you have access to the back-end

Answer (score 0):

I Normally use Vuex to store the token and then I put `` axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${store.getters.token}`; `` Inside the main.js, then the token is always send with the axios requests